# python bind not working

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, tkinter-canvas

I have the basic screensaver program. I want to bind Mouse button 1 to delete everything on screen, but when I press the Button-1 I get this error:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: delete() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

.
.
.
.
This is my program:

```
import tkinter
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=1000,height=800)
canvas.pack()
from random import *

entry1=tkinter.Entry()
entry1.pack()





def setric():





    x=randrange(900)
    y=randrange(700)




    global a
    canvas.delete('all')
    farba=choice(("red","purple","blue","lightblue","green","lightgreen"))

    if a>-90:
        a=a-10
    else:
        a=-10


    if entry1.get()=="":
        canvas.update()
        canvas.after(3000,setric)
        a=0


    else:

        canvas.create_text(x,y,text=entry1.get(),font="Arial 40",fill=farba,angle=a)

        canvas.after(2000, setric)
def delete():
    canvas.delete("all")
a=0        
setric()

canvas.bind('<Button-1>',delete)
```

Even when I change what is in the def delete I still get the error.
Thanks for your time! I am new to this so I have no idea where is the problem
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

Functions called via bindings are automatically passed an object that represents the event. Your `delete` method needs to be able to accept this parameter even if you don't use it.

```
def delete(event):
    canvas.delete("all")
```